# Unexpected parameters definition using Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have such controller

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IActionResult> GetCsvAudit([FromQuery] ReportDto request)
{
    return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(Ok());
}

public class ReportDto
{
    public DateTimeRange ActionDateRange { get; set; }
    public PhiResourceType OrderBy { get; set; }
    public string PhiResourceTypeIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

DateTimeRange is configured for Swagger as follow:

```
c.MapType<DateTimeRange>(() => new OpenApiSchema()                                       
{                                                                                        
    Description = "Date range",                                                          
    Type = "string",                                                                     
    Title = "Date range",                                                                
    Example = new OpenApiString("2020-11-15T00:42:13+00:00 - 2020-11-16T00:42:13+00:00"),
});
```

The problem is the Swagger still wants me to provide every DateTimeRange property in query while I'm using the `[FromQuery]` attribute, when I want it to expects me to provide the string `2020-11-15T00:42:13+00:00,2020-11-16T00:42:13+00:00` for it.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark field/property as `internal` or `protected` or `private`, it will be ignored automatically by swashbuckle in swagger documentation:

```
 public class DateTimeRange
{
    
    internal string Start { get; set; }

   
    internal string End { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, my question might be unclearly formed.
I don't want Swagger to expect me to provide every property for a class. I want to provide one string in query like `2020-11-15T00:42:13+00:00,2020-11-16T00:42:13+00:00` (there're two dates delimited by comma). I have ASP.NET binder implemented for parsing it from the string to the `DateTimeRange` class.

Comment: You can see my updated answer and see if it helps you.

Comment: In this way, I cannot successfully bind, you can see if there is a way to bind successfully.

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks!